# How to center align div even the width is 100%

Tags: css

I am using a `<div>` container and set that container to 100%. Inside that container i have mentioned several `<div>` with 50% and it align to left side. 
Now my question is, whether can i center align the main  container to align center. So that my inner  container align to center. Please help me.

My html code is,

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="co1">
           <p>content</p>
     </div>
     <div class="co2">
           <p>content</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

My css code is,

```
.container{
width:100%;
}

.co1{
width:50%;
}

.co2{
width:50%;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Comment: try with margin:0 auto

Comment: This question has been asked **so** many times before...

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin` CSS property to centralize the Div.

**For instance**

`margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-left:0 auto;
margin-right:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is done with the auto margins which work horizontally only:

Add the following to your CSS for the 2 DIVs inside.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set margins to auto.

```
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
```